# Back button showing on root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

In my application I have a navigation controller. Everything appears to be working fine apart from I keep getting an unwanted back button in my root view. For example

**This is how it appears without selecting any options (how it needs to be always)**
[image]

**This is how it looks after I select an option and go back**

[image]

How can I get rid of the back button (on the root view controller shown below only)?

Comment: Pure storyboard segue (show)

Comment: It seems that you don't use popViewController in your option screen but you push again to this root viewController. I imagine that your navigation stack actually is: rootviewController -> Collection/pull -> rootViewController (another instance).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html take a look at this.

Comment: check my updated answer.thanks

Comment: something is seriously messed up in your navigation hierarchy, could you post something about your e.g. storyboard, maybe?

Comment: check my update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide your back button in the specific view controller (in your case your root view controller). Add this code to your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: You’re welcome, had the same problem few days ago. If you could just mark this answer as correct it will help others saving time. Thanks

Comment: Will do when I can

Comment: It seems like a hack

Comment: Did you test to press to the empty space? Anything happen?

Comment: Yes tested it, nothing happened @Hoa

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing your RootController from other Controller thats the reason you are getting this back button.

There are two ways you can remove this button. Either Always POP when you are travelling back to RootView or hide the back button on your RootView.

To hide back button use following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
```

To pop:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];// If you have pushed from RootView controller

[self.navigationController popToViewController:YourRootViewController animated:true]; // To travel back to RootView controller from any Controller
```

Hope this will help you;

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code.**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true)
}
```

**To go back to main or root VC:**

```
  func backToMain() {
 // If you want to go back to the previous view controller
  navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

 //If you want to go back to the root view controller
 navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You this line of code,

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```