# How I can use back navigation button in viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi everyone :) I'm new in iOS development and I don't know how to make one thing. I have such viewcontroller which is connected with tab bar controller:

[image]

as you can see this is not a TableViewController but ordinary view controller with table. In table I have some cells and I will need to open another view with back button when I press on certain cell. For example in android I used dialogfragment with toolbar where back button was placed but as I can see, in ios we don't have smth like that. I also heard about navigation controller but I think that in such situation it won't help me :( I have such select function for this table in this view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            print("1")
        case 1:
            print("1")
        case 2:
            print("2")
            // I need to add it here
            
        case 3:
            print("3")
        default: break
            
        }
    }
```

So maybe ios has some ability to add toolbar to viewcontroller with back button without nav controller? I see that I can add this element to my viewcontroller but I can't add button and as I see my toolbar overlaps system bar :(

Comment: You need to embed the navigation controller in your view controller.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly please? because I don't understand you :(

Comment: whether your tabBar is just a tabBar or UITabBarViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So maybe ios has some ability to add toolbar to viewcontroller with back button without nav controller?

No. It's either you use `UINavigationController` OR manually add a button (`UIButton` or `UIBarButtonItem`).

The first one automatically adds a **back button** in your `navigationController's` `navigationBar`.

The latter will need a selector, in which you will provide how you want to go back to the previous screen.

Please also know the difference between **pushing/show** and presenting viewControllers.

```
Push/Show --- Pop.

Present --- Dismiss.
```

I suggest go through the basics of navigations in iOS. Perhaps start from here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4284-your-second-swift-4-ios-11-app/lessons/22

Comment: can you say, which method will be better in my situation? because for me building nav controller looks more complex than adding toolbar with button to view controller

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. There are really a lot more ways to do what you want. Using navigation controller is way lot easier than what you think. But I guess since you're asking for an opinion, I'd say continue on not using navigation controller, as also I can see in your question you're somewhat building a custom header/navBar, and not using a navigation controller usually is for that kind of thing. But remember that navcon is part of iOS, and you should learn that asap.

Comment: in general I tried to replace more screen item of tab controller to nav controller and then from nav controller move to view controller which was presented in my question body, but you was right about toolbar which was added from nav controller :(

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have two choices to achieve it:

1.1 Replace your MoreViewController with a NavigationController, then embed your viewController (the VC with table view inside) in a navigationController.

The hierarchy will be: `TabBar -> NavigationController -> More`

1.2 Embed TabBarController inside a navigationController. It is more harder to trigger navigation step, but it achieves another effect: `the detail viewController fully overlaps the tabBar`. It's because it fully overlap NavigationController and TabBar is inside NavigationController. For 1.1, the detail view doesn't overlap the tabBar.

The hierarchy will be: `NavigationController  -> TabBar -> More`

2. Embed your detail view in a navigationController. By default, it'll show navigationBar without backButton, because your detailView is the root ViewController of NavigationController. You can force to show backButton as in: [Back button showing on root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263754/back-button-showing-on-root-view-controller)

- What method to use? It depends on what you're showing, UX. As you can see, on Facebook application, sometimes you see a viewController is shown from bottom to up, sometimes you see a viewController is shown from right to left. It they're not randomly choices.
- One more thing, for overlap system status bar, you should use safe are layout guide instead of top as in: https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/playing-it-safe-with-safe-area-layout-guide-b3f09bdc71fe